# select from table where a=1 and a=2

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a four requirement (may be four select is ok) where I need to find from single table, if customer has

```
a. apple and samsung 
b. no_apple and no_samsung
c. apple and no_samsung
d. no_apple and samsung
```

my table be like...

```
cust_name device
john      apple
john      samsung
dave      apple
tim       samsung
patrick   nokia
rick      nokia
```

so expect output be like...

a:- output ( both apple and samsung)

```
count(*)
1
```

b:-output (no_apple and no_samsung)

```
count(*)
2
```

c:-output (apple and no_samsung)

```
count(*)
1
```

d:-output (no_apple and samsung)

```
count(*)
1
```

Comment: Please, show your current attempt.

Comment: Question title does not match question itself. In any case, SQL has `and` and `or`, you can pretty much compose your code from plain English.

Comment: @ astentx .........for case a:-      ```select count(*) from cust_info where (device='samsung' and device='apple'); ```

Comment: Obviously `device='samsung' and device='apple'` is constant false

Comment: @astentx thats why i need help..i am just a beginner :)

Comment: You need to learn about conditional aggregation or set operations. `device='samsung' and device='apple'` is anyway wrong, you shouldn't use this pedicate if you are a beginner or not, because it is pointless.

Comment: do i use sub query instead ?  ```select count(*) from cust_info where device='samsung' and cust_name in(
select cust_name from cust_info where  device='apple');```  but i hoping if current attempt is possible.

Comment: Add your expected result as a table to your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in a single query using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN num_apple > 0 AND num_samsung > 0 THEN 1 END)
         AS apple_and_samsung,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN num_apple = 0 AND num_samsung > 0 THEN 1 END)
         AS no_apple_and_samsung,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN num_apple > 0 AND num_samsung = 0 THEN 1 END)
         AS apple_and_no_samsung,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN num_apple = 0 AND num_samsung = 0 THEN 1 END)
         AS no_apple_and_no_samsung
FROM   (
  SELECT cust_name,
         COUNT(CASE device WHEN 'apple'   THEN 1 END) AS num_apple,
         COUNT(CASE device WHEN 'samsung' THEN 1 END) AS num_samsung
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY cust_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (cust_name, device) AS
SELECT 'john',    'apple'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'john',    'samsung' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dave',    'apple'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'tim',     'samsung' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'patrick', 'nokia'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'rick',    'nokia'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | APPLE_AND_SAMSUNG | NO_APPLE_AND_SAMSUNG | APPLE_AND_NO_SAMSUNG | NO_APPLE_AND_NO_SAMSUNG |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

---

You can also do it by `PIVOT`ing twice:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  COUNT(DISTINCT device) FOR device IN (
    'apple' AS apple,
    'samsung' AS samsung
  )
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(cust_name) FOR (apple, samsung) IN (
    (1, 1) AS apple_and_samsung,
    (1, 0) AS apple_and_no_samsung,
    (0, 1) AS no_apple_and_samsung,
    (0, 0) AS no_apple_and_no_samsung
  )
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a1d388b3b85c32270216bd262d07f18)*

Answer (score 1):

You might add proper `HAVING` clauses for each case after `GROUP`ing by `cust_name` column such as

```
a) 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cust_name)
  FROM t
 GROUP BY cust_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN device ='apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       * SUM(CASE WHEN device ='samsung' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;

b)
SELECT SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT cust_name))
  FROM t
 GROUP BY cust_name
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN device ='apple' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       * MIN(CASE WHEN device ='samsung' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1;

c)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cust_name)
  FROM t
 GROUP BY cust_name
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN device ='samsung' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       * MIN(CASE WHEN device ='apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
       
d)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cust_name)
  FROM t
 GROUP BY cust_name
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN device ='apple' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       * MIN(CASE WHEN device ='samsung' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa772af8d0977d1c097b3d7c519484a0)</kbd>